# Something Wrong With "Windows Installer" (Windows 8.1 x64)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, installer

I think something wrong with "Windows Installer" in my "Windows 8.1 Core x64" (With latest updates) operating system.

**Symptoms:**

- Can't install some softwares. Installation gives "Error 1603: Fatal Error During Installation."
- I have a Windows installation disc. I want to upgrade to Windows Professional edition. When i insert the installation disc and run Setup.exe nothing happens. Doesn't even see Setup.exe in Task Manager. It runs and dissappear instantly.
- I try to fix the problem by using "Windows Fix It" on this link: http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/tr , when i run it it says some error happened and can not continue to solve problems. It doesnt give any technical information about the error.

**What i tried :**

- With command prompt,  Dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth after this command Sfc /Scannow . It doesn't find any problems.
- Checked if "Windows Installer" service is running. Found out that it's running and even tried to stop it and restart the service. No problem here.
- With command prompt tried these commands :  "Msiexec /unregister" , "Msiexec /regserver"
- Checked if system-drive has proper rights for "System" user. It looks like "System" has full rights on system-drive.
- Cleaned temporary folders with Ccleaner.
- Searched for registry problems with Ccleaner.

**Additional information about my operating system:**

- I'm %100 sure that it doesn't has any malware, spyware, rootkit or virus. Scanned whole system with well known softwares.
- Operating system doesn't have any security software running in background when trying to install something. So, nothing trying to block installations.
- Operating system doesn't have any 3rd party background service or runing 3rd party applications when trying to install something.
- Drives are not encrypted.
- Operating system is up-to-date. Installed latest updates with "Windows Update". No problem here.
- System restore is disabled in all drives. There is no system restore points stored. (Because of performance issues)
- All drivers are up-to-date.

Reinstalling the operating system is not an option for me. Because i have installed 100+ games, 100+ applications. I can't clean install all of them again :(

**Some info about me:**

I have lots lots lots of experience with Windows Operating systems and i love to heavy customize Os. Maybe i did something wrong this time i don't know. I like to come across these types of problems and solving them. But this time i failed.

What should i try?

Comment: did you check TrustedInstaller has the correct perms?

Comment: I don't see "TrustedInstaller" in system-drive's permissions. I'll look at this thanks.

Comment: glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

I give TrustedInstaller full permissions on system-drive and problem solved!